# Modern jack-of-all-trades cheap OPAMPs?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, design, components, component-selection

I am trying to design my first "big" project, and I have to choose the OPAMPs to use. The problem is that I am feeling overwhelmed by all the possibilities.

I feel tempted to just stick on the LM741 or LM358, but after reading around (i.e. there http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/lM741-versus-lM386.91454/), I see that a lot of people say that there are modern opamps  available at    approximately the same price with simply better specs.

All of this to say: which are the modern jack-of-all-trades cheap opamps that can work in a lot of different applications?

I am asking this here because all I have found is about audio, not about electronics in general. I need these information for a signal conditioning circuit.
I have to work in a bandwidth similar to audio (0-40kHz), and I need low offset (around 5-7 mV) and low noise (around 5mV at 10kHz)(by the way, is this really "low" noise or it is just normal noise?). 
I have to pilot an ADC converter (so no need for high currents).

If you need more information please let me know.
Thanks in advance to anyone that will answer!

Edit1: Changed the "low offset" to 5-7 mV and rephrased the "low power" requirement since it was misleading.
Also, after reading all your answers, I am starting to think that the TL054 or maybe the TL052 would work nicely in my project (since i need to use 2 unity-gain buffers and 2 unity-gain inverters).

Comment: Expect to have your question closed shortly, as shopping questions are frowned on here.  Most of the large electronics suppliers have parametric search machines that you can use to search for op-amps that meet your needs.  Try Mouser or RS, or any of the other bigs names.

Comment: Is it really a shopping question? 
I have looked around the internet and there is nothing that can easily answer this question, and I assure you the quantity of opamps around is intimidating for newcomers, even with parametric search machines. 
It would be great to have some basic reference about what "the experts use and know it's working", like the LM741 or the LM358 were 20 years ago.

Comment: I haven't voted to close, but you've got one close vote already.  Some of the folks here are stricter, some are more relaxed.  You would do better to describe what you are doing, pick an op-amp you think would match, then ask here if it is a good choice and whether there are any gotchas to using that particular chip.  Also consider that what may be a good, readily available, general part for one person may be a hard to get exotic for someone else.

Comment: A proper spec of what you want is needed - try considering this answer I gave a few days ago: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203196/is-there-any-science-or-trick-to-determining-a-replacement-op-amp/203199#203199

Comment: 741's are a pretty poor choice these days. High current consumption, need for (relatively) high voltage power supplies, low bandwidth, comparatively low gain, not rail-rail input or output.

Comment: I think tl07x or 08x are the go to cheap random op amps nowadays.

Comment: Digikey component selection guide is an immensely useful tool. Subset as required based on parameters.
http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/linear-amplifiers-instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/2556125?k=opamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"All of this to say: which are the modern jack-of-all-trades cheap opamps that can work in a lot of different applications?"
I would say: there is none ! Although all opamps are in fact just opamps, you noticed that there are a lot of them, there must be a reason for that. The reason is that they all have their own purpose and are designed with a certain range of applications in mind.

You say you want a "jack-of-all-trades" but later you mention: "a signal conditioning circuit. I have to work in a bandwidth similar to audio (0-40kHz), and I need low noise and low offset (around 1 mV), and also low power."
So a "jack-of-all-trades" will not do !
Low noise audio: I'm thinking NE5532

Low noise AND low power usually contradict so you'll have to compromise, what is acceptable ? Cheap also ? Hmm, that makes it even more difficult.
You will have to search for yourself. You can play with your requirements on Digikey or Farnell, sort on price and see what you get.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I added those informations just to give an idea about the project I am working on, but now that I think about it maybe I was too strict. 1mV is really small.
I added "low power" as a way to say that I don't need to use high currents as input/output (this is just a circuit for signal conditioning that will pilot an ADC), I'm sorry if it was confusing: I'm not required to use an opamp specifically designed for low power applications.

Comment: +1 for searching on Farnell. I also sort by availability to get a feel of what is popular among the EE engineers.

Comment: There, I made you think about your requirements a bit more  narrowing down your search. Keep going and you'll find a suitable opamp.